# New Construction Basement Subfloor/Finishing System

Tags: insulation, basement, subfloor

Moved into a new construction home at the end of 2022 with an unfinished basement in Iowa. Starting to research DIY options and am starting with the subfloor and cant come to a conclusion on "best" options.

My goal with the entire basement finish it to be very moisture and thermal conscious. Half of the basement will be carpet, the other half LVP, with decent loads (shelves, gym equipment, furniture, etc) on relatively small portions of the floor. Currently have a couple of load bearing walls, but no "outside" walls, or room walls, which will be needed as the basement gets finished.

I came across DriCore R+ product which I like in theory, but a lot of the feedback I read online seems to express concerns over damp air theoretically getting through the insulation layer gaps and impacting the OSB layer/flooring above. Is this a real concern? I'm not sure. Kind of a similar scenario for the DriCore Insularmor + OSB for carpet/load-intense areas. Worked out to around $2.8/sqft for R+

Then considered doing something like DMX 1-Step, 1/2" rigid foam (Foamular R-3), with 7/16 T&G OSB on top, tapcon'd to the concrete. DMX would provide a solid air/moisture barrier, foam helps keep the floor warmer, and OSB for carpet/load-intense areas, but maybe thats overkill? Worked out to like $2.5/sqft locally

Saw a Home Renovision (youtube channel) video on putting 2" rigid foam on all the walls w/ a gap to allow airflow from the subfloor up the walls and out, then building standard 2x4 walls off of the foam, but how would you go about connecting the thermal/air/moisture barrier from either something like DriCore or DMX to the rigid foam on the walls?

I know there are a million ways to tackle the problem, but I'm trying my best to remain code-compliant in my DIY and be conscious of potential moisture and temperature. Is DriCore enough assuming I already have a vapor barrier under the foundation? Or is my money maybe better spent on a "more complex" system like DMX+foam+OSB? Or are both overkill for new construction?

Comment: Since it's a new build, did they put any insulation and/or vapour barrier under the slab?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. This is _very_ broad and bordering on opinion based. Please take the [tour] and read about [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit] this to refine it to one, very specific question. Feel free to ask several questions at a time, if you'd like, nobody will frown at that around here.

Comment: @MattS I believe its a code requirement in our area to install a vapor barrier under the slab. I'm not confident on insulation, the concrete is still fairly cool to the touch (maybe 60f?), I would guess not.

Comment: What's wrong with 1/2" XPS with taped joints and a 1/2" layer of OSB on top? Why can't the subfloor dry out through the concrete floor? Why does it need to dry through the walls?

Comment: Your DMX and rigid foam seem redundant. Rigid foam doubles as moisture barrier and insulation.

Comment: @popham If a small/medium amount of water got under the subfloor (think small crack in foundation, etc), my hope is the raised platform of the DMX would allow that water to find its way out a bit easier than if the foam was directly in contact with the concrete. It also adds an R1 ish vs the R3 of the foam

Comment: I suppose though, DMX airflow would achieve the same thing at <1/2 the cost of DMX one-step, just without the additional R-1